# How to apply an AR(MA) model to a prewhitened signal?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I have two (vehicle velocity) signals that should consist of similar "latent" drivers, but have different autocorrelation structures. The driver-signals are quite nasty statistically, so I'm not attempting to model them.

I can get quite nice results by prewhitening the signals using AR(1)-residuals, but these are very difficult to interpret in "real world terms" (ie. velocities). So what I'd like to do is to prewhiten one of the signals and then add the AR-model of the other signal to this, so that I'd have two signals with same autocorrelation structures.

It may be that there is a very simple method for doing this, but unfortunately I haven't found one, or it maybe impossible. I guess it should be sort of an inverse of the Yule-Walker method. One also that is quite close is to use arima.sim with innovations, but with the difference that I don't have innovations, but residuals.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436569/how-to-apply-a-arma-model-to-a-prewhitened-signal

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have an ARIMA filter, you can restate this as a pure AR by simply multiplying out the ARI and then dividing by the MA. This would be a pure auto-regressive formulation which is called the PI WEIGHTS ( see any book on time series analysis ) . The right-hand side constant might take you some to time to figure it out but I am sure you will. Use this pure right-hand side equation in conjunction with your residuals and you will get a realization of a process that will have "the same acf" as the series that was used to identify the ARIMA Model. Of course what you will have will be a realization of a sample ACF which of course would depend on the input "error/noise vector".